# How does a hook work when called multiple times in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Why does the loading state of true never get logged, but logs when function is async in the follow codesandbox below? When calling the same hook in a function what is happening?

**code**

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-worker-sjqvz)

```
function App() {
  const [loadingWithUseState, setLoadingWithUseState] = useState(false);
  const [loadingWithReducer, setLoadingWithReducer] = useReducer(
    (acc, next) => ({ ...acc, ...next }),
    { loadingWithReducer: false }
  );

  const onClickWithUseState = () => {
    setLoadingWithUseState(true);
    setLoadingWithUseState(false);
  };

  const onClickWithReducer = () => {
    setLoadingWithReducer({ loadingWithReducer: true });
    setLoadingWithReducer({ loadingWithReducer: false });
  };

  const onClickWithUseStateAsync = async () => {
    setLoadingWithUseState(true);
    await delay();
    setLoadingWithUseState(false);
  };

  const onClickWithReducerAsync = async () => {
    setLoadingWithReducer({ loadingWithReducer: true });
    await delay();
    setLoadingWithReducer({ loadingWithReducer: false });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("loadingWithUseState changed to", loadingWithUseState);
  }, [loadingWithUseState]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("loadingWithReducer changed to", loadingWithReducer);
  }, [loadingWithReducer]);

  console.log("re-render", { loadingWithUseState, ...loadingWithReducer });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={onClickWithUseState}>
        {" "}
        trigger load with useState{" "}
      </button>
      <button onClick={onClickWithReducer}>
        {" "}
        trigger load with useReducer{" "}
      </button>
      <button onClick={onClickWithUseStateAsync}>
        {" "}
        trigger load with async useReducer{" "}
      </button>
      <button onClick={onClickWithReducerAsync}>
        {" "}
        trigger load with async useReducer{" "}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

P.S i want to build a mental model of what happens when you call multiple hooks together

Answer (score 0):

When you set state, ReactJS batches the state updates for performances reasons. So, when you call `setLoadingWithUseState(true)` followed by `setLoadingWithUseState(false)`, React will batch those two together, so you won't see the first update.